# Is "do so so that" in the following sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality

Is the sentence correct? Can the word "business" used in this context? By the word "host" I mean an owner of a house who entertains.

*Hospitality is one of the traits of a friendly and welcoming person. And a good host's **business** is to **do so, so that** their guests could feel comfortable and make themselves at home.*

I'm concerned about the grammar as well.( "...do so, so that..."). Is it incorrect usage or can I leave the wording as it is? If it is wrong, I would appreciate if you suggested several
possible variants of expressing the same idea.

Comment: No; some action/s would need to have been specified.  'And a good host's business is to be hospitable, so that ....'

Comment: As @EdwinAshworth says, the *actual* example cited here is syntactically invalid. But it's not difficult to contrive a context where it's perfectly grammatical to have at least ***three*** consecutive instances of ***so***. As in "You had nearly 100 people in your pub last night, landlord! You should lock the door after the first 10 customers arrive" - "Yes, officer, and thanks for that advice. Tonight I will do **so, so so** many people won't be here spreading disease". Okay - so it's "ugly". Syntactically it's fine.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you very much for your answer. Could you please correct my above sentence? I struggle to come up with a good, gramatically perfect variant.

Comment: I've already started a grammatical rewrite. Just follow up by changing 'could' to 'can'.

Comment: Replace "do so" with "provide that".

Comment: Not to nitpick, but I don't think of "hospitality" as a human trait; it's rather a kind of treatment or a kind of business.  M-W supports this.  If "hospitableness" were a commonly-used word I would suggest using that instead.  It's not, so I might suggest "being hospitable" as the trait.

Answer (score 2):

The double *so* in *do so, so that* is not a problem.

But you don't have an antecedent for your first *so*, which is a pronoun that means [*such as has been specified or suggested*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/so). You haven't specified anything. Also change *could* to *can*:

> ***Being hospitable** is one of the traits of a friendly and welcoming person. And a good host's business is to do so, so that their guests
> **can** feel comfortable and make themselves at home.*

If you don't like the double *so*, you can change the pronoun *so* to *that* (and drop the following *that*):

> *Being hospitable is one of the traits of a friendly and welcoming person. And a good host's business is to do **that**, **so their**
> guests can feel comfortable and make themselves at home.*

I would further suggest that you drop *their*, since you technically don't have an antecedent for it. It's not the noun *business*. It wants to be the noun *host*. But you have only *host's* — a possessive, not a noun. Even if you accept a possessive antecedent (as many do), you still have a mismatch — a singular *host* and a plural *their*:

> *Being hospitable is one of the traits of a friendly and welcoming person. And a good host's business is to do that, **so guests**
> can feel comfortable and make themselves at home.*

Lastly, here's what I would do:

> *Hospitality is one of the traits of a friendly and welcoming person. And it is a good host's business to be hospitable, ensuring that
> guests are comfortable and feel at home.*

Comment: I know Americans sometimes use ***to do*** in ways we Brits never would. But it seems to me that first rephrasing should be *And a good host's business is to **be** so*, since ***so*** there refers back to ***being** hospitable*, not ***doing** [hospitable activities?]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I did struggle with that, but I decided that *do* was idiomatic. *What are you doing? —> I'm being hospitable.*

Comment: Yes, I wouldn't want to overstate my reservations here - I probably "struggle" with the construction in much the same way as you. It's just that you eventually tip one way where I go the other (each of us having "slight misgivings"! :)